# Replacing single HDD on laptop with two HDDs

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have two 500GB hard drives (non SSD) in my laptop. One of them died today, and I need to replace it. I know when replacing memory (i.e. RAM) it's a good idea to make sure that I install identical sticks of RAM rather than mixing/matching RAM from different manufacturers. Is the same true for hard drives? Or can I safely install drives with different specs (e.g. RPM, SSD/HDD, different manufacturers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install drives with different specifications no problem.

- Differing manufacturers has no effect
- Different RPM speeds, 5400 RPM vs 7200 RPM, will cause the faster RPM drive to have faster read & write speeds.

However, If you decide to put an SSD in you will almost certainly want to install Windows on that drive and format **(After Making Backups!!!**) the HDD to use as storage for files and less commonly used programs. Boot times and general usability (access times for files, the speed at which programs open, etc.) will be better as well.